# Blacklist recipient email addresses

Tags: postfix, spam, spamassassin

I have a mail server on Ubuntu using Postfix and Dovecot and SpamAssassin. In Postfix I am using "plus addressing" via the `recipient_delimiter` option. So, for example `foo_junker@me.com` and `foo_stupid@me.com` are valid and actually deliver to the `foo` account.

Some of those addresses have gotten scraped/sold and are now heavy sources of spam (such as `foo_dropbox@me.com`). I'd like to block all email addressed to a specific list of addresses.

I edited `/etc/spamassassin/local.cf` to:

1. Uncomment this line: `shortcircuit USER_IN_BLACKLIST_TO on`
2. Add this line (above the shortcircuit): `blacklist_to foo_dropbox@me.com`

After I restarted spamassassin (`/etc/init.d/spamassassin restart`) emails sent to the blacklisted address still come through unharmed.

How can I hard-nuke these emails so I never see them?

Answer (score 1):

Use this line to blacklist emails sent directly to foo@me.com:

```
blacklist_to foo@me.com
```

And add the following line to blacklist emails sent to any foo alias (with "_" as recipient_delimiter):

```
blacklist_to foo_*@me.com
```